# Convert T-values from Poisson regression to Standard Errors

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, interpretation, standard-error, poisson-regression

I am trying to summarize results from an article for a review (available for free [here](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Bisakha-Sen/publication/4985742_The_Relationship_between_Beer_Taxes_Other_Alcohol_Policies_and_Child_Homicide_Deaths/links/5eebcde0299bf1faac62655d/The-Relationship-between-Beer-Taxes-Other-Alcohol-Policies-and-Child-Homicide-Deaths.pdf), I am looking at table 3), and thus want to find Standard Errors (SE) to compute confidence intervals. The article I am looking at gives the results of a Poisson regression as Incidence Rate Ratios (IRR) (that comes from exponentiating the calculated coefficients) - and t-values, which is not what I am used to.

From my interpretation of [this article](https://www.bmj.com/about-bmj/resources-readers/publications/statistics-square-one/7-t-tests), $$\mathrm{SE}=\frac{\mathrm{IRR}-1}{\mathrm{Tvalue}}.$$  After a few tests, I get reasonable confidence intervals for this - eg. when the article says the result is significant, the confidence interval does not include 1 - but am I right? Or should I derive the $\mathrm{SE}$ from $\log(\mathrm{IRR})$ instead? Or use a different formula? I am a bit out of my league here.

Here is an example of my calculations - for example using an IRR of $0.76$ and a t-value of $1.96$:

$$0.76 - 1 = -0.24 \implies
\mathrm{SE} = \frac{-0.24}{1.96} = -0.122$$

The confidence interval is then given by: $$\exp(\log(\mathrm{IRR}) \pm 1.96 \cdot \mathrm{SE}),$$ results in: $$0.76 \left[0.60 ; 0.97\right]$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted a statistics professor at my faculty and the author of the paper - the solution is:

SE_logIRR = log(IRR)/Tvalue

and the example calculation becomes:

SE_logIRR = log(0.76)/1.96 = -0.14002

and the corresponding result using the formula from the question:

0.76 [0.60 ; 0.97]